# CakePHP 1.3 Shell can't find AppModel class

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, console, cakephp-1.3

I'm migrating a CakePHP 1.3 app from an old server to a new one, the website works fine but the Shells fail with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppModel' not found
```

And the error points to the declaration of a model that extends from the AppModel class. It also somewhat strangely prints the contents of the AppModel class to stdout. Full stack trace below.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppModel' not found in /home/andyburchill/src/site/app/models/account.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/console/cake.php:0
PHP   2. ShellDispatcher->ShellDispatcher() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/console/cake.php:665
PHP   3. ShellDispatcher->dispatch() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/console/cake.php:139
PHP   4. Shell->initialize() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/console/cake.php:337
PHP   5. Shell->_loadModels() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/console/libs/shell.php:180
PHP   6. ClassRegistry->init() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/console/libs/shell.php:257
PHP   7. App->import() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/libs/class_registry.php:143
PHP   8. App->__find() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/libs/configure.php:962
PHP   9. App->__load() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/libs/configure.php:1043
PHP  10. require() /home/andyburchill/src/site/cake/libs/configure.php:1067
```

I'm running the shell from the root directory with the following command:

```
./cake/console/cake queue
```

The most notable difference between the servers is the PHP version, the shells are working on PHP 5.4.9 and are not working on PHP 5.5.9.

I have been googling this for a couple of days, usually people seem to get this error after upgrading to CakePHP 2.x and the fixes don't work for CakePHP 1.3.

I'm beginning to think the only solution is going to be upgrading to 2.x, but this is not a trivial task.

Is there something I can do in the mean time to get this working?, can anyone suggest troubleshooting tips?.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cakephp, but if you are using composer, perhaps try running `composer dumpautoload -o`.  Otherwise, if the file is namespaced, you may need to import the class using the `use` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, but cakephp 1.3 is pretty old and pre-dates composer and namespaces.

Comment: Then simply require the class file.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I had tried that previously but your suggestion led to me notice the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I feel a bit silly now.

I had tried Raphael's suggestion of requiring the class file previously but I decided to try again and noticed that the AppModel class file started with a short open tag instead of `<?php`.

After changing it the shells now work.

Comment: `It also somewhat strangely prints the contents of the AppModel class to stdout` This is the indicator that that was the problem. The file existed, but did not contain any (valid) php code.